# Why are unplaced part titles creating empty pages in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context, context-mkiv

I made a book which is divided into parts, with `\part{}`. I want these parts to appear in the table of contents, but do not need them to appear within the document itself. I added `\placehead=no` to the `\setuphead` settings, which makes the title not appear, however, when `\setuppagenumbering` is set to `alternative=doublesided`, two completely empty pages are created.

```
\setuphead[part][number=no, placehead=no]
\setuplist[part][alternative=c]
\setuplist[title][alternative=c]
\setuppagenumbering [alternative=doublesided]
\starttext
    \definecombinedlist[content][part,chapter]
    \placecontent
    \part{Animals}
        \chapter{Birds}
        \chapter{Snails}
    \part{Plants}
        \chapter{Flowers}
        \chapter{Mushrooms}
\stoptext
```

The `\part` commands seem to be creating empty pages at page 2, 3, 8, and 9. Without the `\part` titles, these pages disappear.

How can I have parts in my document which are invisible, but not in the table of contents, and which also do not create blank pages in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page break is controlled independently by the *page* switch.
The structure levels `\part` and `\chapter` default to the value *right*, which means in double-sided context that the respective headings are always located recto at the top, hence the extra blank page if the command is encountered on odd pages.
(The `page` key inherits functionality from the [`\page` macro](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/page).)
To suppress the break you need to set it to *no*:

```
\setuphead[part][number=no, placehead=no, page=no]
```